# WPF Bind ItemSource to Property of Instance in Array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, binding

Let's say I have a class `Organisation`:

```
public class Organisation(){
   public string Name{
      get;
      set;
   }
   public string Code{
      get;
      set;
   }
}
```

Then I create an array of `Organisation`:

```
public Organisation[] Organisations;
```

The organisation information is stored in an xml and are filled into the array, which works great.

My problem is, that I'd like to bind the ItemSource of the Combobox to the Name property of my Organisations.

It would be very easy if I just have an array of strings which represent the names:

```
public string[] OrgansationNames = new string[]{"Organ1", "Organ2" /**/};
```

I could then easily bind like this:

```
ItemSource="{Binding Path=OrganisationNames}"
```

Obviously it is a little more complex and I need something like this:

```
ItemSource="{Binding Path=Organisations[].Name}"
```

**It is not clear to me how I should specify the Path in this case...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DisplayMemberPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
<ComboBox ...
          ItemSource="{Binding Path=OrganisationNames}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Additionally, you can use [`SelectedValuePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property, which will specifiy the path to the property that is used to determine the value of the `SelectedValue` property.

```
<ComboBox ...
          ItemSource="{Binding Path=OrganisationNames}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="ID"/>
```

If you have not any `Id`, then you can  set `SelectedValuePath` to `Name` also.

Comment: I tested it and it works (!) without specifying a SelectedValuePath. What is it supposed to solve?

Comment: You can remove it, The `SelectedValuePath` property specifies the path to the property that is used to determine the value of the SelectedValue property.

Comment: This is absoluty amazing! I didn't know about SVP. OMG thank you so much. This will save me some calls :) Will accept in 7 min...

Comment: @Farhad Jabiyev: just to complete the answer. if you needed to display something more that just a single property in each item, e.g. FirstName and LastName and Photo, you can use ItemTemplate istead of DisplayMemberPath: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx